# Excell 2016 - Is this average time correct?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, excel-2016

So I am trying to find my average time in Excel and I have been using the average function but even though I do not know what the exact value should be I know that what was being returned was way off. So I googled Excel time format and followed the instructions and changed my time from MM:SS format to H:MM:SS format; because the article said that way I am guaranteed to get correct averages when I use Excel's native average function.

However, I am running Excels average function on mixed values like the below:

```
1:20:30
0:04:00
0:00:30
0:00:05
--------
Average: 0:21:16
```

Can someone just please share their expertise with me and verify that the above average calculation is correct that I obtained by just easily using Excel's native average function.

I just want to be sure before I change everything on my spreadsheet.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "verify that the above average calculation is correct"? It took me about 3 seconds to calculate the average in my head, so why don't you do that yourself? Do you know how an average works?

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag I know how an average works but I am not familiar with doing it in time format. I tried googling how to do it so that I could verify it by learning how to do it manually first but I came across things about doing it in Excel and did not find anything I could really use.

Comment: Well, you add up the times and divide by 4.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag thank you very much. I just wanted verify as I have never done average with times before.

Comment: This is a great Q in my eyes - it's clear to me OP has requested confirmation of whether this is indeed the average; and is something I often find myself, after this many years, still sometimes 'getting stuck on' trying to make sense.  It can be a confusing topic for some (myself included).

Comment: @JB-007 thank you so much for that kind and humble response. I feel a lot better now after readying your reply. I was thinking of deleting the question to be honest but I am glad I still kept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with times and their various formats/representations can be tricky in Excel - sometimes I convert to serial and then multiply by 24 to ascertain the number of hours in the day, other times not.  In your case, this appears to be straight forward and can easily be verified.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98GdIyUCWGYkEJnhf?e=rvXp5A)/screenshot refer:

Mathematically: you can determine the number of hours, minutes, seconds directly from what you have using respective equations as follows:

```
=hour(E4)
=minute(E4)
=second(E4)
```

Determining the average is then a trivial exercise by summing and dividing by the count (4), which reconciles (as can be seen).

[image: Screenshot]

Let's apply logic too:  average of 21 mins looks about right - consider equivalent scenario of average running time for 4 athletes, where one of them takes 80 mins and the others take under 5 each - average time will be around 20 mins (~80/4).

Comment: Thank you so much for this very thorough and great answer. You have really helped me to better understand this.

Comment: np mate.  glad to be of service/assistance :)